# Which is better: MORE data from server, LESS client computation, or vice-versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, client-server

I have a client-server web app I'm working on. There's a point in the initial loading of the client-side where I need to process some JSON data from the server-side db to get it in the right format... Which essentially entails adding a bunch of empty JSON objects to it (thus making entire JSON array bigger). This formatting calculation is somewhat trivial (no need for a super-computer), so it can be done on either the client or the server.

So the **2 choices** I have for implementation are:

1. **Format JSON data on server, send MORE data to client**
2. **Send LESS data to client, format JSON data on client** (extra client computation)

I can think of pros and cons for both choices...

- Choice #1, consistently compute the formatting, but increase number of packets that must be sent for initial load.
- Choice #2, minimize number of packets that must be sent, but add
  extra computation to clients with varying or unknown performance.

Out of these 2 choices, is there a "best-practices" solution which I should typically lean towards?

Comment: To solicit opinions, you should probably find a discussion forum, or maybe the [chat area](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) of SO.

Comment: This depends on what exactly it is your doing? If it's static data needed right away, and not too much, clientside is OK. If it's the same operations everytime, using a memory cache on the server like APC for PHP, I'd go for serverside, but again, it all depends on what exactly it is your doing, there is no "this is better for everything" answer? Otherwise I agree with user1689607, this is not a forum either!

Comment: An alternative to the chat area would be the jQuery forums http://forums.jquery.com

Comment: A question in need of context...

Comment: @KevinB: Why? This would be far more generalized than that specific code library.

Comment: @user1689607 A lot more than just jquery gets discussed on the jQuery forums.

Comment: I think this question has fallen victim to a wikipedia-esque moderation war. I'm sad, because I found this question interesting.

Comment: @KevinB: Believe it or not, there's an entire world outside jQuery.

Comment: Phew...  I didn't mean for this to be an seen as starting opinionated discussion, was hoping someone could give me a rather definitive "best-practices" answer. Sure I left it somewhat ambiguous implementation-wise, but I was just trying to get to the core issue...

Comment: @adamb: I wouldn't take it as a mistake on your part. Your question is valid, well written, and personally, I'd love to see the answer.

Comment: @adamb Your question is interesting. It may be a little bit open-ended and chatty, but that also depends on the people that answer. I hope my answer and TheManiac's may help you, though they are opposite!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good and interesting question. I'd rather choose option #1 because you'll never know about the features of a client device. However, if your program runs on a server (normally with a powerful hardware) the processing time will be independent of the client device, which could be a mobile phone with reduced computing capabilities.

Comment: There are two people (so far) that have no idea of how to use the downvote button. Any arguments to downvote, please?

Comment: Same chumps that downvoted my answer I guess. I get the flagging as nonconstructive, but why the downvotes?

Comment: Don't know. I also understand the question may be unappropriate for this site, but I'd like to know what is the bad point of my answer to argue it.